# Calling function defined in an IIFE function from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, iife

I have a IIFE function in a file called test.js i.e.

```
(function mainIIFE() {
    "use strict";
    var print_name = function(first, last) {
        console.log(first + " " + last);
    };
}());
```

How would I call print_name in an html file. In my head, I have

```
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
  </head>
```

and

```
<script>
    new print_name("Bob", "Downs");
</script>
```

later on in my html file.

But when I try to run, it's not recognizing the print_name function.

Comment: The idea of calling an IIFE is inherently nonsensical.

Comment: That said: if you change `var print_name = ...` to `window.print_name = ...` it should work. But don't call it with `new` because that also doesn't make sense.

Comment: IIFE stands for Immediately-Invoked Function Expression, so how exactly do you expect to call it? It sounds like you want an IFEE to create a function that is available in the global scope so you can run/call it. Is that correct?

Comment: You might want to look into the Revealing Module Pattern instead.

Comment: Why is an IIFE needed whatsoever?  I think you're over-complicating things

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to call a function that is initialized in an IIFE.

Comment: Why? That IIFE doesn't do anything except **prevent** you from calling it from outside the IIFE.

Answer (score 2):

Since you declare `print_name` with `var`, its scope is local to the IIFE, so you can't call it from outside there. You need to assign to `window.print_name` to make it global.

```
(function mainIIFE() {
    "use strict";
    window.print_name = function(first, last) {
        console.log(first + " " + last);
    };
}());
```

It's also not clear why you're using `new` to call the function, since it doesn't fill in an object.

Answer (score 2):

You can return the function and store it in a variable. This is essentially the same as assigning it to `window.print_name` inside the IIFE since the new variable will be in global namespce

```js
var print_name = (function mainIIFE() {
    "use strict";
    var print_name = function(first, last) {
        console.log(first + " " + last);
    };
    return print_name;
}());

print_name('Foo','Bar')
```